# Excel - trying to get Follow Hyperlink to call dynamic Outlook Object

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Here is the code I have assigned in my worksheet Module

```
Public Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim sendName As String

    For i = 1 To 60
        If Target.Name = "NOTIFY" Then
            sendName = i & "test"
            Call TestMail(sendName, "ERRORreport", "sendFile")
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that I need each cell instance of `NOTIFY` to call a unique `TestMail` subroutine.

Comment: Why `Exit Sub` in the else part? Also how more than one cell can have the `Name` "Notify"? Or is it the value that you are checking?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are incrementing your For ... Next loop by 1 outside of your If ... Then statement.  This will guarantee that you skip every other value of i.